# No puedo guardar valor de textarea a mysql por ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, textarea

Al momento de querer actualizar un dato que tengo en un *textarea* y enviarlo por *AJAX* para, finalmente guardarlo en mi BD, no lo hace, me dice que no fue definida dicha variable.

editar_factura.php

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="datos_factura">
                        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Nota</label>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <textarea name="textarea" rows="3" cols="5" class="form-control input-sm" id="nota_cliente" name="nota_cliente" onkeyup="countChars(this);" placeholder="Escriba alguna nota o comentario"><?php echo $nota; ?></textarea>
                                <p id="charNum" style="font-size:12px;">200 caracteres restantes</p>

    </form>
```

editar_factura.js

```
$("#datos_factura").submit(function(event){
          var id_cliente = $("#id_cliente").val();
          if (id_cliente==""){
              alert("Debes seleccionar un cliente");
              $("#nombre_cliente").focus();
              return false;
          }
            var parametros = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/editar_factura.php",
                    data: parametros,
                     beforeSend: function(objeto){
                        $(".editar_factura").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                      },
                    success: function(datos){
                        $(".editar_factura").html(datos);
                    }
            });
             event.preventDefault();
        });
```

y finalmente editar_factura.php

```
        $nota  = $_POST['nota_cliente'];
        $debe = $_POST['debe_pago'];
        $debe2 = $_POST['debe_pago_2'];
        $sql="UPDATE facturas SET id_medico='".$id_medico."', nota='".$nota."', debe1='".$debe."', debe2='".$debe2."' WHERE id_factura='".$id_factura2."'";
        $query_update = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Todos los datos se me guardan excepto el valor que tengo dentro del *textarea*; ya he visto el código una y otra vez y no sé cual pueda ser el problema.

Me da el error: `Notice: Undefined index: nota_cliente in C:\xampp\htdocs\LAB\ajax\editar_factura.php on line 30` y es el único que no me guarda el valor en la BD, los demás sin problemas.

**Actualizacion**

Si quito el *textarea* y lo dejo como un *input type text* no me da problemas y si me envía el valor pero con el *textarea* no puedo.

Comment: Tienes un error al crear el TextArea `<textarea name="textarea" rows="3"` el atributo name="textarea" quitalo

Comment: Hola mi amigo Cesar Romero ya lo quite y sigue sin guardarme la informacion del textarea me dice: Notice: Undefined index: nota_cliente in C:\xampp\htdocs\LAB\ajax\editar_factura.php on line 30 y me llega vacia esa variable las demas sin probelmas pero la del extarea me llega vacia

Comment: Luego de esto `var parametros = $(this).serialize();` haz un `console.log(parametros)` verifica que este serializando el textarea.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código PHP donde procesas la petición.

Comment: en que parte meto esto mi estimado? console.log(parametros)??

Comment: habia leido en unas paginas que habia que definir el #textarea pero no me funiciono

Comment: Triby alli esta el codigo PHP

Comment: Luego de esto `var parametros = $(this).serialize();` haz un `console.log(parametros)` verifica que este serializando el textarea. Esto es en el submit antes de la realizar el ajax

Comment: Buenos dias, disculpa que no haya contestado es que no tenia internet desde la tarde que se fue la señal, y ya me imprime la cabecera de todos mi pagina editar_factura.php y por cierto ya si lo pongo como un input tipo text no me da problemas, pero si lo pongo como textarea no me envia ningun valos, a que se debera??

Comment: Tienes duplicado el atributo `name` es muy probable que al momento de enviar los valores te cree conflicto al leer el valor de ese `textarea`

Comment: Como bien dice @FernyCortez, es muy probable que te esté serializando el primer atributo `name` que encuentra en el `textarea`, debes dejar un solo atributo `name` y usarlo para recuperar el dato en la la superglobal `$_POST`.

Comment: Muchisismas gracias y si no me habia dado cuenta del doble atributo que tenia como he estado  viendo codigo dia y noche se me paso por alto este vergonzoso detalle, sin mas me despido deseandoles a todos los que me comentaron con esta grandiosa observacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi elimnando el atributo duplicado.